# IPhone 4 and 5 different resolutions: problems

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator, resolution

Sorry, perhaps because I'm not English, I don't know, but I cannot find any resource to a couple of questions; maybe I'm using not the correct words..

I would like to know something more about the different resolutions of the iPhone 4 and 5.

First of all: how can I tell my iPhone Simulator to simulate the "letterbox" graphics if I develop an app optimized for iPhone 4 resolution??
I would like to see how it appears but I have not the iPhone 5 yet

Second: what happens on the iPhone 4 if I design an app for the iPhone 5 resolution?
I mean, what does an iPhone 4 user see??

Can you please recommend me something article or similar to learn something more about these problematics?
Thanks

***EDIT***

I was making right!

The only things that makes the app running in letterbox mode with IOS 6 + iPhone 5 is the presence of the Default-568h@2x.png file for the splash screen.

I restar both the iPhone5 and Xcode, clean the project and compile it again. It works.

Answer (score 1):

First: There are different simulators for each iPhone type.  To change between them, open the simulator.  Go to the Hardware menu bar item, then change which you want under device.

[image]

Second: You should be designing interfaces that scale however you can determine if you have a larger screen and change how it looks on the iPhone 5.  If you are using standard components Xcode will try and upscale everything to look proper.  However you should test to make sure it looks how you want on each device.

Comment: I changed the simulator to iPhone Retina 4 inch but the App is not "letterboxed". The simulator just adds some white space on the bottom part of the screen... where I'm wrong?

Comment: Oh wow sorry.  Because you're compiling the app with the latest simulator you won't see letterboxing.  Letterboxing only currents with apps compiled with the last version of Xcode and the iPhone 5.  Xcode 4.5 will not create letter boxed apps.

Comment: I'm downloading the 5 and 5.1 Simulator through Xcode. Then I'll try to run my app with those one. I realized my app whit SDK 6 and the deployment target is 4.3. Is it correct? But what about users who have iPhone 5 with IOS 6? Will thy see my app letterboxes? Sorry, it's seems a real mess!

Comment: As long as you are using Xcode 4.5 that can compile for the iPhone 5, your users will not see letter boxing.

Comment: This is not true. Xcode 4.5 can compile for iPhone 5 in letterbox mode.